# ACE editor autocompletion keywords in upper case

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I have an ACE editor with a custom highlight mode, based on sql mode, and all is working fine, but I am defining keywords in upper case, and when autocompleter shows the available options, all of them are in lower case.

I have checked the old sql mode (before my modifications) and the behaviour is exactly the same.

Is there any way of converting this options to upper case?

I have review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753185/ace-editor-auto-completion), but I have been unable to find a way to do it.
I have also tried to remove all `toLowerCase()` functions into `ext-language-tools.js`, but still showing options in lower case.

Thank you!

Comment: this looks like a bug in ace, try opening an issue on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very dirty workaround, but you can try tweaking `ext-language_tools.js` by adding the following.

Where the code reads:

```
this.filterCompletions = function(items, needle) {
    var results = [];
    var upper = needle.toUpperCase();
    var lower = needle.toLowerCase();
    loop: for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {       
        var caption = item.value || item.caption || item.snippet;
        if (!caption) continue;
```

Change it to read the following, where `'keyword'` and `'builtinFunctions'` are the groups of completions you want to capitalize:

```
this.filterCompletions = function(items, needle) {
    var results = [];
    var upper = needle.toUpperCase();
    var lower = needle.toLowerCase();
    loop: for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; i++) {
        if (item.meta === 'keyword' || item.meta === 'builtinFunctions'){
            items[i].name = items[i].name.toUpperCase();
            items[i].value = items[i].value.toUpperCase();
        }
        var caption = item.value || item.caption || item.snippet;
        if (!caption) continue;
```

Comment: Finally I did another workaround creating a custom completer in the controller, with this solution it is not needed to modify `ext-language_tools.js`. I can share the full code if you want. Anyway, your solution works fine, so I marked it as a accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, a custom completer is another way forward, I agree. I chose to leave the keywords provided by the the language file(s) and create custom completer for tables and columns, but of course there are multiple ways of tackling this issue

Comment: Can you share the code with the custom completer please?

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea there you go: https://gist.github.com/yuvalherziger/aa48782568c6914b55066d290ff88360
Please note that this works on a certain version of Ace Editor, and the gist doesn't include the boilerplate code you need in order to get Ace up and running. Let me know how this works out for you, would love to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a clean solution using a custom completer:

```js
const customKeyWordCompleter = {
  getCompletions(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
    if (session.$mode.completer) {
      return session.$mode.completer.getCompletions(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback);
    }
    const state = editor.session.getState(pos.row);
    let keywordCompletions;
    if (prefix === prefix.toUpperCase()) {
      keywordCompletions = session.$mode.getCompletions(state, session, pos, prefix);
      keywordCompletions = keywordCompletions.map((obj) => {
        const copy = obj;
        copy.value = obj.value.toUpperCase();
        return copy;
      });
    } else {
      keywordCompletions = session.$mode.getCompletions(state, session, pos, prefix);
    }
    return callback(null, keywordCompletions);
  },
};

this.editor.completers = [
  customKeyWordCompleter,
  customCompleter,
];
```