# In ace editor, how to change the popup into uppercase

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

1.Ace editor is strong but not well documented. I use it as my SQL editor but the autocompletion comes in lower case, I edited the mode-sql.js keywords into uppercase but doesn't work, where I can change this?

2.In the future, I also want to read my db files and generate a list of the dbs, tables and so on and I want them in the autocompletion schema, which part of ace should I concentrate?

Currently I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="editor" style="height: 500px; width: 800px">hahaha</div>
<div id="commandline" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; height: 20px; width: 800px;"></div>
</body>
<script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="src-noconflict/ext-language_tools.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var langTools = ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/sql");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/tomorrow");
    editor.setOptions({
        enableBasicAutocompletion: true,
        enableSnippets: true,
        enableLiveAutocompletion: true
    });
</script>
</html>
```

[image: this is what it looks like]

Comment: You will probably need to change the auto-completion function in the Completers library. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36205378/3596851 if this solution helps you

Comment: @Harshapps thanks that helps. Just confused why ace is so strong but poorly documented.